# Polymorphism and overriden methods: Eclipse has a bug?

Tags: eclipse, polymorphism, overriding

It's rather a meta question, so its not that I don't understand polymorphism.

Suppose you have a class and its super class.

The super class has a method *print*, it prints out "Super".
The sub class overrides this method it prints out "Sub".

If you create two instances, one declared as the super class, the other one as the actual class.

```
SuperClass superClass = new SubClass();
SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
```

Now if you work with Eclipse, if you type superClass. and hit ctrl+space, in the list Eclipse says, that the *print* method belongs to SuperClass.
If you do the same with subClass, eclipse recommends the *print* method of SubClass.

If you simply use:

```
 superClass.print();
 subClass.print();
```

Then, of course the output will be: SubSub. As it should be.

Would you consider this a mistake in Eclipse? Or there is an explanation for this? Thanks!

Comment: Both are print anyway. What is your problem. How are you telling it shows print method of subclass?

Comment: If you say ctrl space on subclass and if you have method in super class which is exposed , then you would get that as well. Since its overriding, it shows only one entry.

Comment: There is no practical problem with it, its a meta question.
That is ok, that it shows only one entry but not the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of code completion as working on the **static view**, the same view that is also taken by the compiler: completing after `superClass.` lets you add `print()` *because SuperClass has a method print()*. Seeing `print()` in `SuperClass` ensures that `superClass.print()` can be evaluated.

This view is different from the **runtime view** (what your program actually does), where the JVM will find an instance of `SubClass` and via dynamic binding invoke the sub class version of `print()`.

Editor, completion and compiler use the static view. If you are interested in the runtime view, you'd typically use the debugger. As a middle road, you may select any method invocation and press `Ctrl+T`, which gives you the list of all implementations that could possibly be invoked at runtime via this method invocation. But nothing short of the debugger will definitely tell you, which version will actually be called at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

When you ctrl space on superClass, how can we expect IDE to identify for which SubClass u have assigned the variable.

If you have two sub class for a super class, do you expect it to show all the methods from both the sub classes.

What happens if it is not final?
What happens if it s a class level variable where IDE Cannot make sure at that point of execution, which sub class instance being hold.

If you need methods from sub class, then add a instance check, type cast and say ctrl space.